# SharePoint Change Log API Attachments

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-2019

I tried to get the details of Share point rest API for change_log  for list or events Attachment Files, if user make any changes in the list item we can easily fetch those details by using getbytitle('List')/getChanges rest API. The same way is there any rest API which will help to fetch details of any Attachments Files if user add, update and delete Attachments in any list item or events.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you team for quick reply and support, i added few more details in the question